# How to make word replacer with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Some website offer this, but is there any simple script for this? Also with form. Thanks

ex: I LOVE YOU --> 1 L0v3 y0u

Answer (score 4):

So you want a `l33t` converter. You can make one by using a dictionary and `replace()`.
Here is a sample:

```
var str = "I LOVE YOU";

var LeetDictionary = {
    'A': '4',
    'B': '8',
    'C': '(',
    'D': '|)',
    'E': '3',
    'F': '|=',
    'G': '6',
    'H': '|-|',
    'I': '!',
    'J': '_|',
    'K': 'X',
    'L': '1',
    'M': '44',
    'N': '|\\|',
    'O': '0',
    'P': '|*',
    'Q': '0_',
    'R': '|2',
    'S': '5',
    'T': '7',
    'U': '|_|',
    'V': '\\/',
    'W': '\\/\\/',
    'X': '%',
    'Y': 'j',
    'Z': '2'
};

for (var l in LeetDictionary)
{
    str = str.toUpperCase().replace(l, LeetDictionary[l]).toLowerCase();
}

alert(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery (an extension library for javascript):

```
<form method="POST" action="#">
   <textarea id="mytext" rows=5 cols=30>I LOVE YOU</textarea>
   <input type="button" name="convert" value="Convert">
</form>

var trans = { 'i' : 1, 'o' : 0, 'e' : '3' };

$(document).ready( function() {
    $('input[name="convert"]').click(function() {
        var value = $('#mytext').val();
        for (x in trans) {
            var patt=new RegExp(x,'ig');
            value = value.replace(patt, trans[x]);
         }
        $('#mytext').val(value);
    });
});
```

Example: [http://jsfiddle.net/HrsZP/](http://Example%20here%20on%20jsfiddle)

Answer (score 0):

Using the *`dictionary`* created by ***[`fardjad`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8221972/how-to-make-word-replacer-with-javascript/8222096#8222096)***, and added some modification to it, and now here is the **ultimate solution** to your question.

Demo: **[`http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/u3pvL/`](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/u3pvL/)**